# How to Add a new Key and Merge the array values in multidimemsional array PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-merge

here's the result of my first function:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [MaidID] => 13
        [Stores] => Array
            (
                [0] => 14
                [1] => 5
            )
    )

  [1] => Array
     (
        [MaidID] => 3
        [Stores] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [MaidID] => 41
        [Stores] => Array
            (
                [0] => 14
            )

    )
 )
```

Then, here's the result of my second function:

```
  Array
 (
 [1] => Array
    (
        [MaidID] => 14
        [Cash] => 10000
        [Debit] => 0
        [Credit] => 0
    )
  )
```

and here's should be the result:

```
   Array ([0] => Array (

        [MaidID] => 14
        [Cash] => 10000.00
        [Debit] => 0
        [Credit] => 0   
        [MaidsID] => Array(
                       [0] => 13                          
                       [1] => 41
     )
   )
 )
```

Is it possible to make it?I need to a new key name MaidsID pointing to the list of MaidID owned by more than one Stores.Please help me, Please be patience in my question, im just a beginner.Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

this code work ok. $a is your first array $b is the second,  $c is result

$a = array (array('Maid' => 1, 'Stores' => array (1,5) ), array('Maid' => 3, 'Stores' => array (4) ), array('Maid' => 4, 'Stores' => array (1) ));

$b = array (array('Maid' => 1,  'Cash' => 10000, 'Debit' => 0, 'Credit' => 0));

```
$MaidsID=array();

foreach ($a as $aa ){
    if (count($aa['Stores']>1)){
        array_push($MaidsID, $aa['Maid']);
    }
}
$MaidsID=array('MaidsID' => $MaidsID);

$c = array_merge($b, $MaidsID);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it here and it was ok. (Just replace $a with your first array and $b with seccond ).
Are you sure that the structure of your arrays is exactly as you have written above?? Maybe there is any problem with that.
You have puted array inside another array? (its not needed i think)

Howerver: For this code:

`$a = array (array('Maid' => 1, 'Stores' => array (1,5) ), array('Maid' => 3, 'Stores' => array (4) ), array('Maid' => 4, 'Stores' => array (1) ));
    $b = array (array('Maid' => 1,  'Cash' => 10000, 'Debit' => 0, 'Credit' => 0));

```
print_r($a);
echo "<br><br>================================================<br><br>";
print_r($b);
echo "<br><br>================================================<br><br>";

$MaidsID=array();

foreach ($a as $aa ){
    if (count($aa['Stores']>1)){
        array_push($MaidsID, $aa['Maid']);
    }
}
$MaidsID=array('MaidsID' => $MaidsID);

$c = array_merge($b, $MaidsID);

print_r($c);
echo "<br><br>================================================<br><br>";`
```

The output is:

Array ( [0] => Array ( [Maid] => 1 [Stores] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 ) ) [1] => Array ( [Maid] => 3 [Stores] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) ) [2] => Array ( [Maid] => 4 [Stores] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) ) )

================================================

Array ( [0] => Array ( [Maid] => 1 [Cash] => 10000 [Debit] => 0 [Credit] => 0 ) )

================================================

Array ( [0] => Array ( [Maid] => 1 [Cash] => 10000 [Debit] => 0 [Credit] => 0 ) [MaidsID] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 ) )

================================================

Isn't this how you want the result?

Comment: @ Denis, Hi Sir, your answer is closest to my question but if you don't mind sir, here should be the result :  Array ([0] => Array (

        [MaidID] => 14
        [Cash] => 10000.00
        [Debit] => 0
        [Credit] => 0   
        [MaidsID] => Array(
                       [0] => 13                          
                       [1] => 41
     )
   )
 )

Comment: @ Dennis, Sir, kindly review my question again. Thank you so much.

Comment: replace:
 `$c = array_merge($b, $MaidsID);`

with:
`$c = array_merge($b[0], $MaidsID);
$c = array ($c);`

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this. Maybe this can help you.

`$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);`

Comment: @ Dennis Omeri, hi sir, thank you for the answer, but I need to add the new key named [MaidsID] pointing to the list of Owned Maid. Thank you sir